# Change anchor text in jQuery mobile without ruining the layout

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

How to change anchor text without ruining the layout? In this case, when I trigger the function, the layout is totally ruined. I want to keep the icon and only change the text.

**HTML:**

```
<a href=# id="change">login</a>
<footer id="footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
  <div id="nav" data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="bottom">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#login" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="bottom" data-transition="flip" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="#info" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="bottom" data-transition="flip">Info</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
  $("#change").click(function(){
    $("li:nth-child(2) a").text("Profile");
  });
});
```

Here is [the jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/xuLS2/).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're trying to **replace** the text in `a` from `link` to `profile`, hence taking off the entire markup inside. You'll have to go more deeper.

When you've set `data-icon=somevalue`, jQM sets the two `span` elements inside the `a` tag, the first being used for you text and the other for your icon. If you need to change the text alone, you have to access the `".ui-btn-text"` class within the `a`:

```
$("li:nth-child(2) a").find(".ui-btn-text").text("Profile");
```

Demo : <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/xuLS2/1/</kbd>

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: glad to help :) pls mark the answer as the...erm.. answer if this has helped you. Also, upvote if u think if this will help others :)